# Django- When using Inline Function process aborted

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I am facing a strange road block in my django Admin.

when i am using `inline=[inlineFunction]`

Then it fires process status aborted error.

Here is my code..

```
 class ApplicationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    """
    inline class Application
    """
    model = Application
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 0
    list_per_page = 2

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'logo':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = AdminApplicationLogoWidget

            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(ApplicationInline,
                     self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    custom Admin Class for category model
    """
    list_display = ['name_row_1', 'create_date', 'hospital', 'speciality',   'sort_order']
    search_fields = ['name_row_1', 'hospital__name', 'speciality__name']
    inlines = [ApplicationInline]
    list_per_page = settings.ADMIN_PAGE_SIZE

    class Media:
        js = (
              'v1/js/jquery.min.js',
              'v1/js/inline/function_categories.js'
        )

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'logo':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = AdminCategoryLogoWidget

            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(CategoryAdmin,
                     self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field,
                                                 **kwargs)

    # Default Select Options in Action
    BLANK_CHOICE_DASH = [("", "Select options")]

    def get_action_choices(self, request, default_choices=BLANK_CHOICE_DASH):
        """
        Return a list of choices for use in a form object.  Each choice is a
        tuple (name, description).
        """
        choices = [] + default_choices

        for func, name, description in six.itervalues(self.get_actions(request)):
            choice = (name, description % model_format_dict(self.opts))
            choices.append(choice)
        return choices
```

When i add `inlines = [ApplicationInline]` in my code then on browser page loads again and again.

On my local server it works fine.

My problem is : When i click on save button then browser only loading again and again and not doing any action.

I think this is not code problem because code is running on my local server(windows machine) but on client server only on a single page that error occurs. I don't know what is error. Because not any fault in my code. Not any error show in console.

Client server is AWS/Linux.

Acc. to me, this error occurs in admin section only on linux server, Not any other server. I check same code run on other server that's working. But only not working on AWS/linux server.

Comment: You need to show the code, not just a random line from it; and you need to tell us what happens, not show a screenshot that looks fine. What does "then fire process status aborted" mean?

Comment: have you tried `import logging`, set to **DEBUG**, and maybe you can find out what is looping?

Comment: PLS show the models.py as well and forms.py if exist

Comment: which version of Django?

Comment: Django 1.8.0 ..........

Comment: @KZombro Yes i debug the code but no any process is showing in console. When i debug my code line by line then before inlines = [ApplicationInline] code is running correctly. But when i use this function then is stop working. This problem is occurs only on single page. On other pages code is running perfectly with use of inlines = [ApplicationInline]

Comment: @SureshRatten Can you run your site from localhost server and read the console log?

Comment: On localhost its working fine. But on live server its create problem. Which is not log in console.

Comment: Just suggesting. Check letter case in all files involved in you code. Some OS are case insencetive and Linux is definitely sensitive. If this error is truly only OS dependent this might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks.. But Letter case is not looking a problem here. I check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your valuable suggestions.

Finally my problem  is solved. I don't know finally problem is what but after changing port 80 to 82 on my host server all of issues are resolved.

May be issue is related or port or in db migration.